# Pre-populating form fields with model data in Sightly/HTL

Tags: forms, aem, sightly, aem-6, htl

I've tried all the HTL context parameters (even 'unsafe'). When I inspect the input, I can see the value intact, but you can't see the value pre-populated in the field. I tried different types of values, different contexts, and different types of input fields. [AEM 6.2]

```
<input type="email" name="senderEmail" value="${userProfile.email @ context='text'}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the value is rendered in page source and also visible in browser inspector, could it be that it's hidden by some weird CSS? Something like `color:transparent`

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible causes. I'll pitch in one, to help get you thinking. Is userProfile available via the use api?

I've made this mistake before:

```
<div data-sly-use.bean="com.beans.Bean">
  ${bean.value}
</div>
// ... other code
${bean.value}
```

The "Bean" isn't available later, outside it's host element.

Comment: The value is present in the dom. It's just invisible.

Comment: If it makes it to the client, we can rule out Sightly/HTL as a problem, as that is processed server side. As Vlad said, I'd suspect CSS. Play around in different browsers, with different CSS. Maybe even remove all other code on the page and re-introduce front-end code incrementally until you've found the causal line.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly this isn't actually about HTL, but rather about the HTML input element itself. You have an input element with a `value` attribute set, yet that value is not displaying in the box. If that's correct, then I'd recommend doing some investigation around *HTML input value not displaying when set*, rather than sightly context issues.

Some possible answer would include css styles hiding the input text or javascript clearing out the values after page load. There are certainly more potential causes, but we'd need to know more about your page to provide a better answer.

To do some of your investigation you can try loading a component with only that input in it and see if that works, that would eliminate any css or js executing elsewhere on the page.